# DJango-Models: Create first row on table and use it as a default for future rows

Tags: python, django

I'm writing a image gallery using `Django` and I have a class named `Gallery` that looks like this:

```
class Gallery(models.Model):
 gallery = models.ForeignKey('self', related_name="parent_gallery")
 title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
 folder = models.CharField(max_length=200) # ex: images/galleries/slugify(self.title)
```

And as you can see, the Gallery has a foreign key to itself. Now, I would like all my galleries to be into a **Base Gallery**. `Gallery.id=0` to be the one in which all the other galleries are in.

I'm getting this error:

```
You are trying to add a non-nullable field 'gallery' to gallery without a default; we can't do that (the database needs something to populate existing rows).
Please select a fix:
 1) Provide a one-off default now (will be set on all existing rows)
 2) Quit, and let me add a default in models.py
```

What I want to do is the following: to create the first gallery with id=0 and after that use it as a default.

Is that possible? how would you go around this?

Comment: Are you trying to add a new field? It isn't clear from your question

Comment: I'm trying to add a new field, yes! a gallery with an id=0, then use it as a default for other galleries. @e4c5

Comment: Since a primary key hasn't been declared explicitly,  this model already has a field called id which is auto increment and primary. It's made for youby django.